# SQLAlchemy bulk insert blob data in Oracle DB

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm trying to make bulk insert operation in SQLAlchemy with Oracle DB, which inserts 60k rows with blob data.

This is how my table and code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE datatables (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    table_name VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    row_id VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    row_data BLOB, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

```
with Session() as session:
    session.execute(
        DataTables.__table__.insert(),
        datas
    )
```

Where `DataTables` is SQLAclhemy class mapping for table and `datas` is list of dicts like this `{'id': 1, 'table_name': 'app', 'row_id': 'version', 'row_data': '....'}`

with such code i got this sql statement

```
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO datatables (id, table_name, row_id, row_data) VALUES (:id, :table_name, :row_id, :row_data)
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.14718s] [{'id': 1, 'table_name': 'app', 'row_id': 'version', 'row_data': b'some_data'}, ...]
```

and it runs forever, even after 30 minutes it is not finished. When I enable DPI trace there are a lot of such rows:

```
ODPI [12912] 2021-12-18 00:07:36.019: ref 0000019C3D15C5B0 (dpiConn) -> 8
ODPI [12912] 2021-12-18 00:07:36.020: ref 0000019C413F0C20 (dpiLob) -> 1 [NEW]
ODPI [12912] 2021-12-18 00:07:36.020: ref 0000019C3D15C5B0 (dpiConn) -> 9
ODPI [12912] 2021-12-18 00:07:36.020: ref 0000019C413F1990 (dpiLob) -> 1 [NEW]
```

However if I use raw sql:

```
session.execute('insert into DATATABLES (id, table_name, row_id, row_data) values (:id, :table_name, :row_id, :row_data)', datas)
```

DPI trace changed to this:

```
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.246: ref 000002486741EAF0 (dpiVar) -> 0
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.246: ref 00000248617D2DF0 (dpiConn) -> 6
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.246: fn end dpiVar_release(000002486741EAF0) -> 0
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.246: fn start dpiVar_setFromBytes(000002486741EBB0)
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.247: fn end dpiVar_setFromBytes(000002486741EBB0) -> 0
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.247: fn start dpiVar_setFromBytes(0000024864E5FDE0)
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.247: fn end dpiVar_setFromBytes(0000024864E5FDE0) -> 0
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.247: fn start dpiVar_setFromBytes(0000024864E601A0)
ODPI [00796] 2021-12-18 00:14:55.247: fn end dpiVar_setFromBytes(0000024864E601A0) -> 0
```

and bulk insert is done in 15 seconds.

SQL statement is same in both cases. Why does it work diffent? Of course I can use raw sql, but I want to use `DataTables.__table__.insert()`, because if table or columns names will change - I don't need to fix sql for this every time.

Comment: Most *probable* explanation with Alchemy you are doing row by row insert. Activate a 10046 trace to prove this.

Comment: 10046 trace? Sorry, i'm not very familiar with oracle debugging

Comment: see e.g. [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof)

Comment: i checked tracing - it's executemany, not row by row. the only difference is when i use ```DataTables.__table__.insert()``` it uses ```dpiLob_setFromBytes```, but with raw sql it's ```dpiVar_setFromBytes```. Don't know why it changes from lob to var and why lob is slower in this case.

Comment: In the case where dpiLob_setFromBytes() is used you are creating a temporary LOB, writing to it, and then transferring from the temporary LOB to the permanent LOB. In the other case where dpiVar_setFromBytes() is used the data is being transferred directly -- it is considerably more efficient, as you discovered!

Comment: Looks like the only option for me is to use ```session.execute(str(DataTables.__table__.insert()), datas)``` to get raw sql. Otherwise sqlalchemy is always using ```dpiLob```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issues like these should preferably be reported as bugs in SQLAlchemy, which you can do at :  https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/  otherwise we were completely not aware of this problem.

in this case we've been alerted to this issue and will seek to update our LOB settings per cx_oracle developers for SQLAlchemy 2.0, which is tracked at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7494

Comment: To be honest, I thought that it was me who was mistaken in something, and not the erroneous behavior of SQLAlchemy. Thanks for reporting issue